# Инструменты для реализации отчетов для Mono

Tags: c#, linux, поиск-программ, fastreport, stimulsoft

Какие инструменты существуют для реализации отчетов для Mono (Linux), аналогичные MS Frameword.NET + Stimulsoft Report.NET (FastReport.NET)?

Answer (score 1):

Есть [TMS Flexcel Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp). Написано, что поддерживает Mono.  Я не использовал, поэтому по возможностям ничего сказать не могу,отзывы ищите в google. И еще один для изучения [i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports/features).